# What does sudo ln -sfn do?

Tags: java, android-studio, java-8, homebrew, zshrc

I installed JDK on my mac for Android studios (which I have done before) and I used Homebrew to install. At completion I got these suggestions? I would like to know if I want system Java wrappers to find JDK, Should I symlink it? and Why would I want it first in my path? Also I am using .zshrc as it is now default Catalina and wondering if I set $PATH variables the same way?

````
For the system Java wrappers to find this JDK, symlink it with
  sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk

openjdk is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because it shadows the macOS `java` wrapper.

If you need to have openjdk first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openjdk/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find openjdk you may need to set:
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openjdk/include"```
````

Answer (score 6):

`ln` is the command creating the links between files, here is [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ln.1.html).

`ln -sfn` means force creating a new symlink.